# How to Force String Type on a Variable?

Tags: bash, variable, array

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USERS=("user1.com" "user2.co.uk" "user3.com")
PASSES=("pass1" "pass2" "pass3")

for i in ${USERS[@]}; do
    echo ${PASSES[i]};
done
```

running this script outputs:

> my-script.sh: line 6: user1.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".com")

However, my values are wrapped in quotes and as far as I know, `echo` isn't an arithmetic operation.

Coming from a PHP background, this is confusing. In PHP we can do:

```
echo gettype($string);
echo gettype($int);
```

which outputs

> string 
>  integer

Yet, the quotes seemingly do not do as I'd think. How do I force string usage instead of treating `user1.com` as `user1` `.` `com`?

Comment: just a general question to the community: should this more be on SO or is ok here?

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to de-reference an *indexed* array with a *string*; your loop should be over the indices of `USERS` i.e. `for i in ${!USERS[@]} ...`

Comment: @steeldriver huh that did it! Can you tell me what adding the `!` before the array does in the foreach loop? (or add an answer for some free rep ;))

Comment: to downvoter: not fussed on the vote, but leave a comment so I can get better :)

Comment: It's an indirection operator,  it produces the indices into the array rather than the list of values. (All Bash variables are essentially strings anyway, but some strings contain numbers,)

Comment: @tripleee thank you :) I guess that makes sense, thanks again :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code expands to

```
for i in user1.com user2.co.uk user3.com; do
    echo ${PASSES[i]};
done
```

which of course makes no sense at all.  The indirection operator produces a list of array indices instead:

```
bash$ echo "${!USERS[@]}"
0 1 2
```

So with that, you can loop over the individual indices.  Let's also add correct quoting.

```
for i in ${!USERS[@]}; do
    echo "${PASSES[i]}"
done
```

For full points, you should not use upper case for your private variables; uppercase variable names are reserved for system use.

Comment: didn't know that bout var names, I just see like every tutorial use caps for variables, happy to know I can go lower :D

Comment: Yeah, it's weird - a lot of popular shell scripting resources contain various errors and stylistic problems.

Comment: ah that's scary.. its like going through w3schools xD